# Given the matrices ${\bf A}, {\bf B},{\bf C}$, how to solve $\bf A\Lambda B = C$ for diagonal $\bf \Lambda$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Given the fat matrix ${\bf A} \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times Q}$ (where $M < Q$), the tall matrix ${\bf B} \in \mathbb{C}^{Q \times N}$ (where $Q > N$) and ${\bf C} \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times N}$, how to solve the following linear matrix equation for *diagonal* matrix ${\bf \Lambda} \in \mathbb{C}^{Q \times Q}$?

$$ {\bf A} {\bf \Lambda} {\bf B} = {\bf C} $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$First, introduce the extremely useful Frobenius $(:)$ product
$$\eqalign{
F:G &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n F_{ij}G_{ij} \;=\; \trace{F^TG} \\
F^*:F &= \frob{F}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
F:G &= G:F \;=\; G^T:F^T \\
H:\LR{FG} &= \LR{HG^T}:F \;=\; \LR{F^TH}:G \\
}$$
and a diagonalization identity involving the Hadamard $(\odot)$ product
$$ \diag{A\cdot\Diag{x}\cdot B} \;\equiv\; \LR{B^T\odot A}x $$
Then approach this as a least squares problem
$$\eqalign{
&M = A\cdot\Diag{x}\cdot B \;-\; C \\
&\min_x\: \frob{M}^2
}$$
Calculate the gradient of the least squares objective function
wrt the $x$ vector
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= {M^*:M} \\
d\phi &= M^*:\c{dM} \\
 &= M^*:\CLR{A\cdot\Diag{dx}\cdot B} \\
 &= \LR{A^TM^*B^T}:\Diag{dx} \\
 &= \diag{A^TM^*B^T}:dx \\
 &= \diag{A^TA^*\cdot\Diag{x^*}\cdot B^*B^T - A^TC^*B^T}:dx \\
\grad{\phi}{x}
 &= \LR{BB^H\odot A^TA^*}x^* - \diag{A^TC^*B^T} \\
}$$
Conjugate the gradient, set it to zero and solve for the optimal $x$
$$\eqalign{
x &= \LR{B^*B^T\odot A^HA}^{\boldsymbol +}\diag{A^HCB^H} \\
{\large\Lambda} &= \Diag{x} \\
}$$
where

$\quad M^+\:$ denotes the pseudoinverse of $M$

$\quad M^T,M^*,M^H\:$ denote the transpose, complex and hermitian conjugates

$\quad\Diag{}\:$ creates a diagonal matrix from its vector argument

$\quad\diag{}\;$ returns the main diagonal of its matrix argument as a column vector

Comment: Amazing mathematical skills! I have one question remaining. If we consider $A,B,C,\Lambda$ as complex matrices, then it follows from $d\phi = Re\left\{[(B^*B^T\odot A^HA)x-diag(A^HCB^H)]:dx\right\}$, where $Re$ is taking the real part. How can we pursue the optimal $x$ in this form?

Comment: The answer has been updated to accommodate complex matrices.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product. May I please ask that shouldn't the Frobenius inner product be modified into $F:G = Tr(F^HG)$ in complex matrices? If it should, 
 I think maybe the term $M^∗:(A⋅Diag(dx)⋅B)$ is in this way equals to $(A^HM^∗B^H):Diag(dx)$?

Comment: And for $\left\|M\right\|_F^2$ , I ofen read from textbook as $Tr(M^HM)$ so that the corresponding $d\phi$ is $Tr(M^HdM+M^TdM^*)$, which can be further expressed as $2Re\left\{Tr(M^HdM)\right\} = 2Re \left\{M:dM\right\}$. Does it have any relationship with $d\phi = M^*:dM$? I am so confused, it seems they are so different.

Comment: I prefer to define the Frobenius product as summing over the elements of a Hadamard product. My definition means that the Hadamard and Frobenius products commute, i.e. $$(A\odot B):C=A:(B\odot C)$$ whereas the Wikipedia definition does not have this property. If a complex conjugate is required, it should be **explicitly** inserted into an equation, not hidden behind a definition.  Also, I can never  remember if Wikipedia conjugates the left matrix or right matrix. Why should I have to memorize their arbitrary choice?

Comment: For complex matrices you must use [Wirtinger derivatives](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.4835) also called the $\mathbb{CR}$ Calculus

Comment: I am very grateful for your help! But based on my knowledge right now, I can not understand it very clearly. Can I consider the optimal $x$
 is exactly the same form if I use that Wikipedia definition of Frobenius inner product?

Comment: Yes, you can derive the optimal $x$ vector using the Wikipedia definition, and it will be identical to the above expression.

Answer (score 2):

By comparing the $(m,n)$ element of matrices $AB$ and $C$, note that

$$C_{m,n} = \sum_{i=1}^Q A_{m,i} \Lambda_{i,i} B_{i,n}$$

This gives $M\cdot N$ linear equations in $Q$ unknowns ($\Lambda_{1,1}, \Lambda_{2,2}, \ldots, \Lambda_{Q,Q}$), if $\Lambda$ is really a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that this is essentially just a set of linear equations, since $$A\operatorname{diag}(x+y)B = A\operatorname{diag}(x)B  + A\operatorname{diag}(y)B$$

Secondly, notice that there are $M×N$ many equations, but $Q$ variables. So depending on whether $M×N ≷ Q$, the system will be over- or underdetermined. When $M×N > Q$, the system generally will not be solveable and the best you can hope for is a minimal residual solution like least-squares. Letting $X= \operatorname{diag}(x) = (δ_{pq}x_q)_{pq}$ we have:

$$\begin{aligned} 
AXB &= \Big(∑_{pq} A_{mp}X_{pq}B_{qn}\Big)_{mn} 
\\&= \Big(∑_{q} A_{mq}B_{qn}x_q\Big)_{mn} 
\\&= \Big(A_{mq}B_{qn}\Big)_{mn, q} ⋅ x
\end{aligned}$$

After which we can flatten the first two axes and use any off-the shelf solver. Example in numpy:

```
import numpy as np

M, N, Q = 2, 3, 6
A = np.random.randn(M, Q)
B = np.random.randn(Q, N)
C = np.random.randn(M, N)


def lstsq(A, B, C):
    """Returns least-squares solution for A⋅diag(x)⋅B = C."""
    M = np.einsum("mq, qn -> mnq", A, B)
    M = M.reshape(-1, Q)  # flatten
    C = C.reshape(-1)  # flatten
    return np.linalg.lstsq(M, C, rcond=None)


x, *_ = lstsq(A, B, C)
diff = np.einsum("mq, q, qn -> mn", A, x, B) - C
print(diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that there is a unique algebraic solution of the equation
$$ C = A\Lambda B $$
Multiplying by $\{X,Y\}$ does not affect the equality, but creates square-shaped matrices
$$ XCY = X(A\Lambda B)Y $$
The main diagonals of each side are also equal
$$\eqalign{
{\rm diag}(XCY)
 &= {\rm diag}(XA\Lambda BY)
 &= \Big((BY)^T \odot(XA)\Big)\,{\rm diag}(\Lambda) \\
}$$
This simple linear system is easy to solve
$$
{\rm diag}(\Lambda) = \Big((BY)^T\odot(XA)\Big)^{-1}\,{\rm diag}(XCY)
$$
Any two matrices $\{X,Y\}$ of the proper dimensions can be used, but the choice will affect the invertibility of the linear system. Some obvious candidates are
$$\eqalign{
X \in \{A^H,A^T\} \qquad Y \in \{B^H,B^T\} \\
}$$
If the original equation does not have a solution, then you must settle for an approximate least-squares solution.  In that case, Greg's analysis indicates that $\,\{X=A^H,\:Y=B^H\}\,$
are the appropriate choices.